# How to fix TypeError: __call__() of arguments error in keras prediction

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to change a repository from  git bun in my own i found a problem with number of arguments,

the part of code that I'm talking about is in :
https://github.com/aSafarpoor/keras_cnn/blob/master/src/predict.py
and i run python predict.py with it's arguments.

but it makes error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
  File "predict.py", line 117, in main
    v = network_eval.predict(specs)
  File "/home/mas/anaconda3/envs/weild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1166, in predict
    f = self.predict_function()
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

it means *keras* prediction function need more arguments but it's not normal,

take care that input is a *numpy* array in a true shape.

the related part in code is :

```
 for c, ID in enumerate(unique_list):
        if c % 50 == 0: print('Finish extracting features for {}/{}th wav.'.format(c, total_length))
        specs = ut.load_data(ID, dim_w=args.wdim,dim_h=args.hdim,win_length=params['win_length'], sr=params['sampling_rate'],
                             hop_length=params['hop_length'], n_fft=params['nfft'],
                             spec_len=args.frame_num, mode='eval')
        # specs = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(specs, 0), -1)
        specs=np.expand_dims(specs,0)
        v = network_eval.predict(specs)####error is here ####
        feats += [v]
```

so what should be the second argument?or what should change?

Comment: Do you have a modified keras version? Because the code in your backtrace does not match the official keras code from github.

Comment: yes but nothing about prediction,the model.py is that part.
in function "vggvox_resnet2d_icassp"  returned is a keras model.

Comment: You are not getting me, if you modified Keras, we cannot really help you, as you could have introduced bugs and we have no idea what modifications you made.

Comment: well,i tried to use a not modified type but it not works again.-same error again-

Comment: Look at this link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1396 , the code in your backtrace does not match with this, as there is a function call in that line, where in the official code there is not. This line of code has not changed in 3 years. Make sure that you are using the official Keras code, without any modifications.

Comment: well i reinstall it and it works,thank you....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a modified Keras version, since the exact same line in the keras official code ([here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1396)) does not have the parenthesis making the function call.

Make sure that you only use the official Keras releases and do not modify its source code, you can introduce bugs and errors that we cannot debug.